# Ember - Pass Event and Other Parameter to Action Handler

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember component, I have a list of strings, and a function that update the string at certain index of the list.

```
animals: computed(function() {
    return ["dog", "cat"];
}),

updateAnimal(value, index) {
    this.animals[index] = value;
},
```

In my hbs, I render the list of strings into text fields, within a `#each` loop. When I `focus-out` the text field, I want to update the string at the certain index.

```
{{#each animals as |animal index|}}
    <textarea
        value={{animal}}
        {{on "focusout" (action updateAnimal value="details.value")}}
    />
{{/each}}
```

But how can I pass in the index to the handler as well?
In other words, how can I pass the event and some extra parameter at the same time?
Thanks a lot for answering my question!!

Comment: Ultimately, I want to create a form that can dynamically add/remove text fields, and the inputs to these fields are linked to a list of strings in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can applay arguments to an action using the [`{{fn}}` helper](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.25/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/fn?anchor=fn):

```
{{#each this.animals as |animal|}}
  <textarea {{on "focusout" (fn this.updateValue animal)}} />
{{/each}}
```

The `updateValue` method will receive the `animal` as first argument and the event as the second argument.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  animals = ['dog', 'cat'];

  @action
  updateAnimal(animal, event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    window.alert(`Changed text for animal ${animal} to ${value}`);
  }
}
```

Please see this Ember Twiddle for the code running: https://ember-twiddle.com/cad87d51ec2e1fdfd88b8a123ba2d7dd?openFiles=components.my-component%5C.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component%5C.hbs

Please note that I modernized your code using Ember Octane primitives. I used native classes, dropped computed property in favor or class field, avoided implicit `this` fallback in template and used `@action` decorator for binding `this` context. It should work similar with the old patterns used in your question. But I think the new Octane primitives are easier to understand.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I know the `fn` from the document: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/
But I wasn't aware that the event is added as the last hidden parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. But one small correction: `fn` template helper is not adding the event. It is only applying some arguments to the function. The arguments passed on invocation stay the same. So it could be used in any context. Not only with events. The function will receive the arguments applied by `fn` helper additionally to the arguments set on invocation by the action handler. This is useful if dealing with components.